# Configuring webapp directory in both Maven and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

In a Maven project that is packaged as a war file, the default "webapp" directory is `src/main/webapp`. Is there a way to configure Maven to use a directory `foo` **that will automatically have the same effect in Eclipse**?

For example, suppose the module has a file `foo/index.html`. I tried added the following to the pom file:

```
<resource>
  <directory>foo</directory>
  <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</targetPath>
</resource>
```

This has the desired effect: Maven puts `index.html` in the root directory of the war. **But when I load the module in Eclipse** and tell Eclipse to deploy to Tomcat, Eclipse ignores directory `foo`: Tomcat never sees `index.html`.

Setting `<targetPath>` to `../` has the same result.

I am aware that I could change the [Deployment Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525117/what-is-target-m2e-wtp-web-resources-in-deployment-assembly) configuration in Eclipse, but I want Eclipse to get its information from the pom file. Is there a way to do that?

Here is my complete pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebApp3</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Example WebApp</name>
  
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>foo</directory>
        <targetPath>../</targetPath>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build> 
</project>
```